# Каким образом можно реализовать view? Есть ли готовые решения?

Tags: android, activity

Всем добрый день. Может кто то подскажет какой view можно использовать для вывода *сетки из изображений*, возможно что бы внутри изображения имели разные размеры, возможно менялись в случайном порядке. Элемент будет располагаться на главном activity. Спасибо.

Comment: Вариант 1: https://github.com/adhamenaya/AndroidMosaicLayout
Вариант 2: https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если сетка статичная то `GridLayout`. Если динамическая - `GridView`.
В GridView посредством адаптера и разметки ячейки можно размещать любой однотипный контент.

Есть куча разновидностей `GridView` и кастомных реализаций. В том числе официальные `Gallery` (устарел), `HorizontalScrollView`, `GridView` и неофициальные `AsymmetricGridView`, `DNDGridView`, `TwoWayGridView`, `QuiltViewLibrary` и много много других.